# DataGridView and Cell Lock?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using vb.net. 
How I lock a specific cell in the DataGridView (not a complete column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the [DataGridViewCell.ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.readonly.aspx) property to true